# execute bitbucket pipeline webhook from remote

Tags: dockerhub, bitbucket-pipelines

I am on docker hub, how can I trigger bitbucket pipeline once images are built successfully?
I want them to run in order:

1. build images
2. trigger bitbucket pipeline

Comment: You mean as soon as you push the image to docker hub?

Comment: yes as soon as images are pushed right way,it trigger remote bitbucket pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

You can send a request when your images finish building on Docker Hub via [Docker Hub Webhooks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/webhooks/).

> You can use webhooks to cause an action in another service in response to a push event in the repository. Webhooks are POST requests sent to a URL you define in Docker Hub.

You can trigger a bitbucket pipeline using a POST request via the `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/pipelines/` URL. 
You can check the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pipelines/#post) for more info.

Comment: I do not how to write the POST URL and some paratemers.

Comment: Is it just me, or is that documentation empty?

Comment: @KevinTing it seems like pipelines was moved from the {username} to the {workspace} namespace. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @focuszheng You might try using pipedream.com, which can receive the webhook from dockerhub and can provide a scaffold for you to POST to this endpoint. It also will handle authentication for you.